# Cannot uninstall MongoDB on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb

I want to completely uninstall MongoDB from my Ubuntu 18.04.

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

The first two commands worked but the last two commands are not working. The following error is showing.

```
rm: cannot remove '/var/log/mongodb': No such file or directory
```

If I hit `mongod` the following error shows.

```
bash: /usr/bin/mongod: No such file or directory
```

If i hit `sudo systemctl status mongodb` the following error shows.

```
mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented >database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-01-05 19:45:53 +06; 1h 3min ago
 Main PID: 18811 (code=exited, status=2)

জানু 05 19:45:53 anon-acer systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented >database.
জানু 05 19:45:53 anon-acer mongod[18811]: Error reading config file: No such file or directory
জানু 05 19:45:53 anon-acer mongod[18811]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
জানু 05 19:45:53 anon-acer systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
জানু 05 19:45:53 anon-acer systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How can I completely uninstall all of the files, configurations and everything of MongoDB from my pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you purged/uninstalled MongoDB, `/var/log/mongodb` and `/var/lib/mongodb` were removed automatically. When you tried to remove those "removed" files explicitly, it threw errors,

```
rm: cannot remove '/var/log/mongodb': No such file or directory
bash: /usr/bin/mongod: No such file or directory
```

Just because there were indeed no such files.

Moreover after you uninstalled MongoDB, there was still a file `/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service` which is used to start/stop/restart MongoDB service via `systemctl`. Since MongoDB was already uninstalled but that file was still there and it was unable to run that service, thus showed `Active: failed`.

Remove that file using:

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
```

And you are done. Try checking its status or starting using:

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

You'll get an error like "Service not found". Now there is no service MongoDB in your system

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install mongodb binary (Manually) to your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic). You need to download mongodb .tgz file from this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=docs#production) .

1) Download it to your ~/Downloads folder and moveit to home directory by typing `mv Downloads/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4.tgz ~/`

2) Then unter it by typing `tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4.tgz` place it here (Home directory /home/). Dont move it from here.

3) Then make a directory at /data/db location and give write permission to thatdirectory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db

sudo chmod -R 777 /data/db
```

4) Now, this is the tricky area. Make sure u r in hme directory by typing pwd (Present Working Directory)

```
pwd
```

it will show

```
/home/<your user name>
```

Then type

`ls -al`

This command will show up all hiddenfile at home directory and search for

`~/.bashrc`

5) Edit the .bashrc file and write

```
export PATH=mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4/bin:$PATH
```

and save the file type `source ./bashrc`

Then type `echo $PATH` at terminal it will display `~/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4/bin:/home/xenon/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

6) Now at terminal type `mongo --nodb`
it will show `MongoDB shell version v4.0.4`

From here , you are all set, go ahead and enjoy mongodb installation. This istallation is bit complex but by this method you can easily control the version of mongodb and use it as per your need.

7) Then start mongod

```
>sudo mkdir -p /var/log && sudo chmod -R 777 /var/log
>mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --logpath /var/log/local.log --fork
>mongo --port 27017
```